# PowerApps Custom Connector AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, powerapps

I am trying to create a Custom Connector in PowerApps so I can connect to our Jira Server.

I am trying to use OAuth Authentication but I can't configure it properly.
I am getting this:

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application: "App Id here"

In Azure I have tried to change the Reply url to several things but with no luck:

- https://tenantName.tenantNamelogin.com/tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
- https://login.windows.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
- http://localhost:31544
- http://localhost:61659/signin-oidc

I have granted several rights (Graph) as admin. I have tried to login with admin accounts and non admin accounts, error remains the same.
I have followed several guides including [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-a-new-application-using-the-azure-portal) and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/azure-active-directory-authentication).

**What is causing this error and what can I do to configure this properly?**

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: The reply url in your code must be the same as the one in azure portal.

Comment: @TonyJu, that's the thing, I don't need to do anything in code, the authentication should be done by the user interface (Microsoft Prompt) but whenever I choose a MS login (admin account or normal which also has admin rights) I get the error. I don't get what is wrong or not properly configured.

Comment: You can use the fiddler to capture the request url, you will find the reply url in the authorize endpoint. Then use this one in Azure portal.

Comment: Something like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345
&response_mode=query
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
&state=12345` Copy the value of `redirect_uri`

Comment: Any luck to get the value of redirec_uri?

Comment: Yes :) https://global.consent.azure-apim.net was the value but setting this in Azure didn't seem to solve the issue ... :(

Comment: Can you paste the url here(Remember to hide the sensitive information)?

Comment: Ofcourse: https://login.microsoftonline.com/GuidNrHere/oauth2/authorize?client_id=AppIDFromAzure&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fglobal.consent.azure-apim.net%2fredirect&resource=https%3a%2f%2fmanagement.core.windows.net%2f&prompt=select_account&state=GuidNrHereAndLocationOfServer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197868/discussion-between-dimitri-and-tony-ju).

Comment: You missed‘ /redirect ‘. Try with https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reply url in your code must be the same as the one in azure portal.

You can use the fiddler to capture the request url, you will find the redirect_uri in the authorize endpoint. Then use this one in Azure portal.

Something like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize? client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e &response_type=code &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345 &response_mode=query &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F &state=12345`

Copy the value of `redirect_uri`