# Swift - Firebase Auth with Microsoft Graph (Redirect URL Problem)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, azure-active-directory

I'm having a problem integrating Firebase with Microsoft Auth in my iOS App.

The login page has been launched and I can sign in by Office365 account but login auth can not be finished because of the below Error :

```html
"AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application:[app-id]"
```

I did check the setting in Firebase and below are the settings I add in the app of Azure Active Directory :

1. Web redirect URL : "*.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler"
2. Supported account types : "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory Multitenant)"

Here are the swift code I implement :

```swift
provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com")
provider?.customParameters = ["prompt": "consent", 
                              "login_hint": "Login Hint"]

provider?.scopes = ["mail.read", "calendars.read"]

provider?.getCredentialWith(_: nil){ (credential, error) in

    if let credential = credential {

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem or have the same problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue with the reply URL (you already have an answer to that below): you should *not* be including the `prompt=consent` custom parameter. This will cause issues for you application.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret What kind of issues will be caused if I include `prompt=consent`? (e.g.force users to provide consent?)

Comment: In many organizations, users are not allowed to consent. In these organizations, admins will consent on behalf of all users. But even when an admin has already consented on behalf of all users, if you force consent with `prompt=consent` users will be blocked (because they're not allowed to consent, and your app is forcing them to re-consent). You should only use `prompt=consent` when you have established that the permissions your app requires have not already been granted.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Noted and will be careful in future usage!! Thank you so much for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When registering apps with these providers, be sure to register the
>   *.firebaseapp.com domain for your project as the redirect domain for your app.

Have you replaced * with your projectName? You can find your Authorized Domain under **Authorized Domains** in firebase console. The redirect uri should be something like

```
https://yourFirebaseApp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
```

Comment: I do replace the with my project name like **https://[project_name].firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler** in Azure 
and I can find `[project_name].firebaseapp.com` in Authorized Domains of firebase console, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @LilingChen Can you  capture the request url? you will find the redirect_uri in the authorize endpoint. Refer to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57476562/10504999

Comment: I tried and I did get the redirect_url with a session like below `https://[project_name].firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?code=[encoded_info]&state=12345&session_state=[session_state]`. This is just the one I set but I still have the sameproblem when signing by my app.

Comment: I restarted to build the whole project, confirmed it by the way you provided and got it successfully!! I really appreciate the way you provide for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the fact that you are using firebase, authentication thought it acts like a web application rather than a native Mac/IOS app. So in your azure console when you want to 'Add a Platform', do not select 'IOS/MacOS' option, as this does not provide an option to add your custom redirect URL provided by you Firebase Console, instead choose 'Web', 'Single-Page Application', or 'Mobile and Desktop Applications'. I tested all 3. Don't know the exact difference.