# SwiftUI - Firebase Authentication with Microsoft

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

Currently I am trying to use **SwiftUI** to build an App and using Firebase Authentication with Microsoft. What I want to do is to login by Microsoft account and get some information by the token. In the past, I did it successfully in this way : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816895/swift-firebase-auth-with-microsoft-graph-redirect-url-problem) but I failed to do it in SwiftUI.

Below is the way I implemented and the app did open the Microsoft Login page and it seemed sign-in successfully but it stopped at a blank page and the origin view didn't show up.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct SignInView: View {

    var microsoftProvider : OAuthProvider?

    init(){
        self.microsoftProvider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com")
    }

    func signIn () {

        self.microsoftProvider?.getCredentialWith(_: nil){credential, error in

            if error != nil {
                // Handle error.
            }

            if let credential = credential {

                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        // Handle error.
                    }

                    guard let authResult = authResult else {
                        print("Couldn't get graph authResult")
                        return
                    }

                    print(authResult.user)

                    // get credential and token when login successfully
                    let microCredential = authResult.credential as! OAuthCredential
                    let token = microCredential.accessToken!

                    // use token to call Microsoft Graph API
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
             Button(action: signIn) {
                Text("SignIn")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SignInView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignInView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with Firebase support team, the problem has been solved.

The team is very thoughtful and helpful. We went through all the setting confirming and narrowed down a few things. In the end, the solution from the team is appended here: [Phone Number Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#appendix:-using-phone-sign-in-without-swizzling)

Besides all the steps which are described in official document, it needs to be sure that **Firebase version 6.13.0** and **Auth SDK version v6.4.0** have been installed.

Then, implementing the below function in SceneDelegate.swift, and the redirect URL can be handled during Authentication flow. The sign-in flow finished successfully and token could be received.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
  for urlContext in URLContexts {
      let url = urlContext.url
      Auth.auth().canHandle(url)
  }
}
```